# How to make foreign key updated automatically once the referenced key has been inserted with new value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a 2 tables like this
[image]

[image]

I have put bmatricno as a referenced key for a foreign key called bmatricno_fk. Ok now i want to insert new data that contain bmatricno and bname for one table which is the first pic. And then i want the column for bmatricno_fk to be updated as well with the same value with the referenced key which is bmatricno. However i failed.

Then i try to insert manually with inserting on 2 tables. Then i have a problem with inserting multiple tables. I know about using transaction with commit because im using PDO. The problem is, since i have to use a code something like `:bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'].` Therefore, i dont know how to use transaction that includes that kind of thing.

my code looks like this. (noob isnt it?)

```
$ses = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];

        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO borrow ( 
                bmatricno,
                bname,
                bdatetime
            ) VALUES (
                :bmatricno,
                :bname,
                NOW()
            )
            ;
            INSERT INTO thesis(
                bmatricno_fk
            ) VALUES (
                :bmatricno
            )
            SELECT serialno, title
            FROM thesis
            WHERE serialno = :ses
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'], 
            ':bname' => $_POST['bname'], 
            ':ses' => $_SESSION['sBorrow'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        }
```

That is my current code. So my question is does foreign key can be updated once referenced key got new value? If not, how to make transaction with the code i stated earlier?Please help me. I need to get this done.

NOTE: You notice that on second pic and column matricno_fk works well because i put an input to insert value, which means manually.

Comment: You cant use the same named placeholder multiple times, although they refer to the same value/variable

Comment: I see..so it only can be used once.. then how should i refer the value for it?

Comment: Once in the same query. You can give it numbers like `:placeholder_1`. And a transaction can have multiple queries, executed one by one as a transaction. Youre doing project for a school it seems

Comment: And you will need to call `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` if successful or `rollback()` if not successful.

Comment: Yeah..seems like it.. what we are taught are basic, but our assignment is pretty.......extreme..anyway if i do transaction, shoud i use the code like query_params?or no need?

Comment: Separate each queries. For  your case 2 insert queries and one select query. It goes like this, begin transaction ->first query->execute->second query->execute->third query->execute->commit. Each query will need their own set of values of `query_params`.

Comment: [This](https://www.html5andbeyond.com/using-database-transactions-pdo-code-example/) is a good example.

Comment: It seems good enough...pretty detail...i will try it out..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Well i did find the solution for my problems.  frz3993 working but i just realized that one of my variables is an array. Therefore i use foreach on query. Since its an array, i'm not sure how to use foreach inside transaction since im in a rush. So i execute one by one query. and put foreach on my second statement like this.

```
$ses = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];


        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO borrow ( 
                bmatricno,
                bname,
                bdatetime
            ) VALUES (
                :bmatricno,
                :bname,
                NOW()
            )
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'], 
            ':bname' => $_POST['bname']
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        }


        //----------------------



        $query = " 
            UPDATE thesis
                SET 
                    bmatricno_fk = :bmatricno,
                    bavailable = 'Unavailable'
                WHERE
                    serialno = :ses
        "; 

        foreach($ses as $s){

            $query_params = array( 
                ':bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'], 
                ':ses' => $s
            ); 

            try 
            { 
                // Execute the query to create the user 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
                // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
            }
        }


        //----------------------
```

I know this solution may not be best practical but well i need to complete it fast and i just have to present it on localhost anyway. Anyway, thanks for helping :)